# ASP.NET Lookup Table

Tags: asp.net

In a C# ASP.Net code behind page I’m retrieving from a SQL database 200+ rows of data each with 2 columns, one column is a unique key and the other column is a numeric value. I then want to write these rows to an aspx HTML element such as `<select>` or to a JavaScript array that I can iterate through, essentially a lookup table.  My question is, are either of these approaches viable or is there a more conventional method of creating a web page lookup table. I know how to iterate through arrays with JavaScript, but I’m just getting into jQuery which would be my iteration preference.
I would appreciate any insightful feedback.
Thanks.

Comment: Something to think about. If these records don't change very often, you may want to cache them in memory on the web server rather than making the call every time you need it. Maybe refresh the cache every few minutes, but if you get a lot of traffic, making the same database call over and over with the same results might waste a noticeable amount of resources.

Answer (score 1):

If having a select element is acceptable, why not use a DropDownList?

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" DataTextField="Column1" DataValueField="Column2" id="ddlLookup" />
```

You can then bind that using

```
ddlLookup.DataSource=yourDataTable;
ddlLookup.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly a viable option.  You can retrieve these values and write them into a JavaScript array like you said.  I've not used ASP.NET for so long that I don't remember if you can put the values into a normal C# array and use that in your aspx page.  At least if you were using MVC you could pass the C# array into your viewmodel for your view to use.